# Difficult boo syntactic macro

Tags: macros, boo

I'm creating a DSL for an extensible card game engine I'm working on, with boo.

I have a card macro that creates a class for a new type of card, and initializes some properties in the constructor. That macro has a few submacros for setting other things. Basically I want it to turn something like this:

```
card 'A new card':
    type TypeA
    ability EffectA:
        // effect definition
```

into this:

```
class ANewCard (Card):
    def constructor():
        Name = "A new card"
        Type = Types.TypeA
        AddEffect(EffectA())

    class EffectA (Effect):
        // effectdefintion
```

The effect definitely needs to be a class, because it will be passed around (it's a Strategy pattern).

So far, I have this simple skeleton:

```
macro card:
    yield [|
        class $(ReferenceExpression(card.Arguments[0])) (Card):
            def constructor():
                Name = $(card.Arguments[0])
    |]
```

Now, I don't know what should I do with card.Body to make the ability macro add code to the constructor while also generating a nested class. Any thoughts? Can this be done with current language capabilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done. Here's how:

```
import Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast 
import Boo.Lang.PatternMatching 

macro card(name as string): 
    klass = [| 
        class $(ReferenceExpression(name)): 
            def constructor(): 
                Name = $name
    |] 
    klass.Members.Add(card["effect"]) 
    klass.GetConstructor(0).Body.Add(card["effect-ctor"] as Expression) 
    yield klass 

macro effect(eff as ReferenceExpression): 
    card["effect"] = [| 
        class $eff (Effect): 
            pass 
    |] 
    card["effect-ctor"] = [| Effects.Add($(eff)()) |]
```

Credit goes to Cedric Vivier for helping me out in the [boo Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/browse_thread/thread/f700c47af4541c7f/3f4c3e7eecab8f9b#3f4c3e7eecab8f9b.).